# Load asynchronously in a div, Ruby On Rails + AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, asynchronous

First I am going to explain what I want to do.
I have a principal page with a navigation bar and a section (div "principal") where I want to load in an asynchronous way the corresponding section when I pulse on the navigation bar. To do this i am usign RoR+AJAX. The problem I have is that when I try to upload a view of a different controller that I am using ( "principal_controller") tells me it cannot find the path.

index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to(principal_noticias_path, :class=>"mdl-navigation__link", remote: true) do %>
        <i class="mdl-color-text--blue-purple-400 material-icons" role="presentation">description</i>Noticias
      <% end %>
....
      <main id="demo-contenido" class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
  </main>
```

noticias.js.erb

```
$.ajax({
url: "xmlposts_path",
cache: false,
success: function(html){
  $("#demo-contenido").append(html);
}
});
$('#demo-contenido').slideDown(350);
```

The problem is that "xmlposts_path" is other controller. I don't know if i    explain very well. Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be "<%= xmlposts_path %>", so ERB can render the path correctly.

Comment: Can we have the error message? on rails server or on browser console you will find error message which couses issue

Answer (score 1):

> I have a principal page with a navigation bar and a section (div
>   "principal") where I want to load in an asynchronous way the
>   corresponding section when I pulse on the navigation bar

The correct terminology is `hover` (not pulse).

Okay, there are a lot of issues with your code. Specifically:

1. You've called `remote: true` on your `link`. I take it that means you want to fire the ajax when you *click* the link, not "pulse" (hover)?
2. Your `Ajax` call does nothing. If you're calling it from your controller's `js` action, you don't need ajax as you're already operating an asynchronous request.
3. I think you're overcomplicating what should be a relatively simple thing.

---

**Ajax**

**A**synchronous **J**avascript **a**nd **X**ML is simply a technology subset which allows you to call "mini" requests through your browser:

[image]

The *async*chronicity of the request means that it can be fired in tandem with your current one. As such, if you have a `remote: true` call on your link, it's simply going to [invoke an ajax request](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L108).

You are firing this initial ajax request, then telling your system to fire another. This goes against all conventions and is considered an [antipattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AntiPattern).

Thus, if you're going to use `remote: true`, you should be expecting the return of the menu fields directly from your controller method:

```
#app/controllers/noticias_controller.rb (?)
class NoticiasController < ApplicationController
   def your_action
      @data = Data.all
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js #-> invokes app/views/noticias/your_action.js.erb
      end
   end
end

#app/views/noticias/your_action.js.erb
$("#demo-contenido").append(<%= @data %>);
```

This is just an example, but should explain the primary issue with your Ajax structure.

---

**Method**

Next we get to your method.

Why are you trying to use ajax to pull menu items? You'll be pinging your server needlessly. Just keep them all in a [`_partial.html.erb`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

```
#app/views/common/_menu.html.erb
# menu items hard coded here
```

You can then integrate the menu into your layout as follows:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= render "common/menu" %>
```

You can achieve the hover effect using either CSS or JS.

There are already great resources to achieve this, so I'll let them help you:

- [CSSWizard](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)
- [TutorialRepublic](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-dropdown-menu-on-mouse-hover-using-css.php)
- [CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/) (VERY GOOD)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting routes error then on the console use

`rake routes` and check for the path which you want to pass

You will find some thing like /controller/action_name/id_parameter

Use exact path the pass on the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

By your code it seems you just forgot to use <%= %>.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<%= xmlposts_path %>",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#demo-contenido").append(html);
  }
});
```